# A cardinality of sets question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sometimes I don't know if I get questions about the cardinality of sets right. For example, what are the cardinalities of the next sets: $A=P(\mathbb{R}$\ $\mathbb{Q})$,$B=P(\mathbb{N}\cup\{\mathbb{Z}\})$, $C=P(\mathbb{N})\cup{\mathbb{Z}}$, $D=(0,1)$\ $\mathbb{Q}$, $E=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x^{3}\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

In addition, is there a way to assure my answer? because sometimes I feel that I am doing right, but apparently I find otherwise.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes my bad. has fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

$A$: $\Bbb R$ is uncountable and $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$, and its power set therefore has the same cardinality as $\wp(\Bbb R)$.

$B$: $\Bbb N\cup\{\Bbb Z\}$ contains just one more element than $\Bbb N$, so it has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$, and $\wp(\Bbb N\cup\{\Bbb Z\})$ therefore has the same cardinality as $\wp(\Bbb N)$.

$C$: $\wp( \mathbb N)$ is uncountable, and $\Bbb Z$ is only countable, so their union has the same cardinality as the bigger one.

$D$: See my comments on $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ in the comment above on $A$.

$E$: The function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ injective (one-to-one), and $E=f[\Bbb Z]$.

Comment: Thanks! the cardinality of $E$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ right? and yet couldn't understand if the cardinality of $D$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. Btw, can tell me if there is a way to assure my answer? maybe other ways of checking if I got it right?

Comment: @user12121: $\Bbb Z$ isn’t actually a cardinality, but yes, the cardinality of $E$ is the **cardinality** of $\Bbb Z$: $|E|=|\Bbb Z|$. The general principle involved in several of these, including $D$, is that if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, $X$ is infinite, and $|X|>|Y|$, then $X\cup Y$ and $X\setminus Y$ have the same cardinality as $X$. $|(0,1)|>|\Bbb Q|$, so $D=|(0,1)|=|\Bbb R|$. Offhand I can’t think of any way to check these results independently, I’m afraid.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Really helped me.

Comment: @user12121: You’re very welcome!

Comment: Clearly $E$ injects the $\mathbb Z$ and so $|E| \leq \aleph _0$, however, I don't see how are you establishing $\aleph _0$ as a lower bound on $E$? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @FD_bfa: The fact that $f$ is injective (one-to-one) ensures that $|f[\Bbb Z]|=|\Bbb Z|$: injective functions preserve cardinality.

Comment: To clarify: if I have an arbitrary set $A$, then are you saying that for any injective function $f:A \rightarrow B$, that $|f(A)|=|A|$? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @FD_bfa: Yes. Such an injection is a bijection from $A$ to $f[A]$, and the existence of such a bijection is precisely what it means for $A$ and $f[A]$ to have the same cardinality.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not really seeing (at least not intuitively) how the injection is a bijection from $A$ to $f(A)$ though. Is there a reference to a proof of this result that you could point me in the direction of? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @FD_bfa: There’s really nothing to prove: the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is injective (one-to-one), because $f$ is, and by definition it’s a surjection onto $f[A]$, so by definition it’s a bijection from $A$ to $f[A]$.